# Value of particular integral of a partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the partial differential equation $$\dfrac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2}~-~\dfrac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2}~=~\sin(x- y)~.$$
For this type of partial differential equation, which of the following is the value of particular integral (P.I) i.e., the value of the expression$~\dfrac{1} {{D_x}^2 - {D_y}^2}~ \sin(x- y)~$?

$1.~$ $-\frac{x}{2} \cos(x- y)$

$2.~$ $-\frac{x}{2} \sin(x- y)+ \cos(x- y)$

$3.~$ $-\frac{x}{2} \cos(x- y)+ \sin(x- y)$

$4.~$ $\frac{3x}{2} \sin(x- y)$

where $~D_x^2\equiv \dfrac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}~$ and $~D_y^2\equiv \dfrac{\partial^2 }{\partial y^2}~$.

Comment: I'm sorry, what are $D^2_x$ and $D^2_y$?

Comment: @LordVader007 I'm also unable to understand what are these? I guess these are differential operators for PDE, $D_x= \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and  $D_y= \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let, $$y= x+c$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{D_x^2 - D_y^2} sin(x-y) &= 
\frac{1}{D_x- D_y}\frac{1}{D_x+ D_y} sin(x-y)\\
&=\frac{1}{D_x- D_y} \int \sin(x-c-x)dx \\
&=\frac{-1}{D_x- D_y} x \sin c\\
&= \frac{1}{D_x- D_y}x \sin (x-y)
\end{align}
Now, consider $$ (D_x- D_y) z= \sin (x-y)$$
Its auxiliary equations are $$ \frac{dx}{1}= \frac{dy}{-1}=\frac{dz}{x \sin (x-y)} $$
from first two members, $x +y = c$

from first and last, $dz= x \sin (x-y) dx = x \sin(2x-c) dx$

therefore, $z = \int x \sin(2x-c) dx$

after integrating, $z = \frac{1}{4}(\sin(x-y)-2x \cos(x-y))$

which does not match any of the options.

Again, checking option $1$,

let $z= \frac{-x}{2} \cos(x-y)$

$z_{xx}= \frac{x}{2}\cos (x-y)+ \sin (x-y)$

and $z_{yy}= \frac{x}{2} \cos(x-y)$

so, $z_{xx}- z_{yy}= \sin (x-y)$

so, option $1$ is correct.